# Python Pandas groupBy condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

I have a dataframe from a CSV file with the following format:

```
"name";"elapsed"
"etl_A";6.13e-05
"stl_A";0.0001
"etl_B";0.001
"stl_B";0.0003
"etl_C";23.2e-06
...
```

With Python Pandas, I would like to convert the dataframe to the following format:

```
benchmark_name;etl_elpased;stl_elapsed
A;6.13e-05;0.0001
B;0.001;0.0003
C;23.2e-06;...
```

I've done simmilar such things in other languages using the respective `groupBy` method combined with a regex expression to extract the benchmark name, however I'm new to Python as well as Pandas. From my understanding, Pandas `groupBy` function behaves diferently  than other languages and I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried something like this:

```
def extract_benchmark_name(full_name: str) -> str:
    return regex.match(full_name).groups()[1]

df = pandas.read_csv(source, header=0, sep=';')
etl_df = df['etl' in df['name']]
stl_df = df['stl' in df['name']]

etl_df['name'] = etl_df['name'].apply(extract_benchmark_name)
stl_df['name'] = stl_df['name'].apply(extract_benchmark_name)
```

however this doesn't look right and also gives me various errors.

Ultimately, I want to combine this with matplotlib to generate a bar chart like this with normalized values comparing etl and stl:

[image: chart]

Any help to do either of these two tasks would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (updated with @TrentonMcKinney improvement):

```
df[['Benchmark', 'Type']] = df.name.str.split('_', expand=True) 
ax = df.pivot('Type','Benchmark','elapsed').plot.bar(color=['b','r'], width=.95, edgecolor='w', alpha=.8)
ax.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(.5,1.01), ncol=2, frameon=False)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @AndyL. Thank you!  I appreciate that!

Comment: Using join is probably overkill. `df[['bm_name', 'name']] = df.name.str.split('_', expand=True)`

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney is correct.  Much better syntax.  Mind if I add it?

Comment: That's fine by me.

Comment: Thank you so much! One thing, I forgot to mention that in the `name ` column, `A` or `B` may themselves contain underscores, which appears to break the code you gave due to the `split` - how can I fix this?

Comment: If you want the right most '_' you can use rsplit with n=1. `df['name'].str.rsplit('_', n=1)`

Comment: Thanks, that worked!! Last thing, is there a way to normalize all the columns such that the maximum of the 2 values for each type is 1.00 (etl[i] + stl[i] / max(etl[i], stl[i]))